# Draggable feedback same size as child

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a swipable cards (similar to the Tinder app) using a `Draggable` widget. The swiping works fine except that I am struggling with figuring out how to set the size of the `Draggable`'s `feedback` to have an equal size as the `child`. The issue is that the `Stack` widget holding the `Draggable` items have a dynamic size depending on the screen size and therefore setting the size to a fixed value is not an option.

I was trying to use the LayoutBuilder with hope that I will be able to obtain the size using `RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;` with following exception `RenderBox was not laid out`. After reading the docs, it turned out that getting the RenderBox cannot be called in the `build` function.

Another option could be to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size`, however this is not that convenient as it returns only the window size where the app is rendered (whole screen).

I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a clue how this can be done.

**Code**:

```
class CardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardStackState createState() => new _CardStackState();
}

class _CardStackState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          return new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Draggable(
                key: ObjectKey('card1'),
                child: new Card(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                  ),
                ),
                feedback: new Card(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: box.size.width, // TODO: how to get same size as child??
                    height: box.size.height, // TODO: how to get same size as child??
                  ),
                ),
                childWhenDragging: Container(),
              ),
              new Draggable(
                key: ObjectKey('card2'),
                child: new Card(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                  ),
                ),
                feedback: new Card(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: box.size.width,
                    height: box.size.height,
                  ),
                ),
                childWhenDragging: Container(),
              ),
              new Listener(
                onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
                  print(event.position);
                },
                child: new Draggable(
                  key: ObjectKey('card3'),
                  child: new Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: Container(
                    ),
                  ),
                  feedback: new Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: Container(
                      width: box.size.width,
                      height: box.size.height,
                    ),
                  ),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### UPDATE

Please use `LayoutBuilder` to construct the `Draggable`. It's builder function receives a constrains param with which you can adjust the size of the feedback. This is much better because you cannot always have a `GlobalKey` if you have a list with dynamic data.

Example:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Draggable(
    child: Container(...),
    feedback: Container (
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
    )
  ),
);
```

---

### Initial post

You can determine a Widget's size by using its GlobalKey. I posted this comment on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6085#issuecomment-639438296) for a ListView, but I think you will be able to use the same example for a Stack.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 25,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    GlobalKey myKey = GlobalKey();
    return Draggable(
      child: ListTile(
        key: myKey,
          title: Text("Tile #$index"),
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Opacity(
          opacity: 0.2,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Tile #$index"),
          ),
        ),
        feedback: FeedbackWidget(
          dragChildKey: myKey,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Tile #$index"),
          ),
       ),
     );
  }
)


class FeedbackWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  final GlobalKey dragChildKey;
  final Widget child;
  const FeedbackWidget({Key key, this.dragChildKey, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Determine the size of the original widget
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = dragChildKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final size = renderBoxRed.size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Material(
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also look at [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407)